# How to sort the columns values in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I have displayed a set of data in the *`ag-grid`*, and the data is of complex type, i.e. values are displayed in the grid using a custom cell renderer.

I have given the option **"sortable = true"** but still columns are not getting sorted, even though I am not able to get value in the `comparator()` function.

Please help me with sorting the column values.

```
const sampleRowData = [
    {
        "field_name": "<some_value>",
        "field_value": "tgb34378eee847334894",
        "original_field_value": "tgb34378eee847334894",
        "_id": "1",
        "_img_id": "300",
    },
    {
        "field_name": "<some_value_1>",
        "field_value": "tgb34378eee847334895",
        "original_field_value": "tgb34378eee847334895",
        "_id": "2",
        "_img_id": "310",
    },
]
```

I want to sort the column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in **ag-grid** defaultColDef can be used for enabling sorting, like below

```js
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";

import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";

const App = () => {
  const [rowData] = useState([
    { make: "tgb34378eee847334894", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
    { make: "tgb34378eee847334895", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
    { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
  ]);

  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: "make" },
    { field: "model" },
    { field: "price" }
  ]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      width: 270,
      sortable: true
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
      ></AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can see "sorting" is working here
[image: Edit Ag Grid React Hello World (forked)]